# Select different CSS style sheet for different browser window sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, centering

I have my div (#box) centering in the middle of the browser window which is groovy for browsers that are 600px vertical or taller. If the window is smaller than that, content at the top of the div gets sheared off, and the scroll bar only scrolls the page up (when I pull the scroll bar down), so it's impossible to see anything hidden above the top edge of the window even when the scroll bar is at its top-most position.

Here's how I center my div--you can see why the top of the div gets cut off in smaller browser windows.

```
{position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 1930px; height: 607px; margin-left: -965px; margin-top: -302px;}
```

(It's really wide to accommodate the animation working on even the widest screens--the width isn't an issue.)

Here's a page to look at: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/
  And my CSS: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/css/basic.css

This is easily fixed in my CSS style sheet, but it seems like I can't have it both ways for monitors greater than 600px and monitors smaller than 600px.

**So, how do I detect a browser window size and then select one of two different CSS style sheets?** One for small windows, another for larger windows? Is there a jquery script that will do this for me?

**Or, is there another way to make my div center in the middle of the browser window with CSS** that will allow scrolling so that the top of the div can be accessed on smaller browser windows?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Frankly your design is the issue and you're trying to solve it with workarounds. For one there are better solutions for vertical centering that won't pull the content under the browser's top edge. Look into `display:table-cell`. Secondly your website is entirely invisible without Javascript which will affect your Google ranking and people like me who run NoScript or disable Javascript out of general concern for security. In short your site breaks the Number 1 rule of HTML/CSS which is to degrade gracefully.

Comment: @spliff, Thank you for taking the time to write! I appreciate your concern. The vast majority of my visitors use javascript. Google can usually read js without any trouble, read more here: http://goo.gl/cPdiM

Answer (score 4):

@media queries are my preference (saw that you don't like them as a solution per se), but they really could do the trick - especially if you adjust your css a little to accommodate.

```
<link...media="only screen and (max-height: 600px)" href="small-device.css" />
    small-device.css = div.container { ... height:500px; margin:50%; ...}

<link...media="only screen and (min-height: 601px)" href="big-device.css" />
    big-device.css = div.container {... height:600px; margin:50%; ...}
```

You may also have a little more luck by removing your absolute positioning and taking advantage of normal document flow. It would help you to add things like `{ overflow-y:scroll; }`
to those hidden-by-screen-height divs.

I think in the end, if you're trying to design around hand-held devices, you'll need media queries to some extent. My Android screen (for example) has 3 display options (low, medium, hi def). All 3 crop pages differently.

Comment: Okay, this looks promising too. I'll give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: @dawson, can you show me some real world code for an example? Thanks again!

Comment: Great article from A List Apart...with working site example. Check it out:http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

Comment: @dawson--you win! Very satisfying stuff. Thank you for turning me on to media queries!

Comment: @dawson Oh... Wait, it's not working with IE... Please see my original question, I've updated it to reflect this and added the code I'm using... Thanks!

Comment: Can't seem to update question, Here's my code:
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/basic.css"  media="screen and (min-device-height: 600px)"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/basic-alt.css"  media="screen and (max-device-height: 599px)"/>

Comment: `media="screen and (max-height:599px)` -> nix "device-"

Comment: If you follow inheritance rules of CSS you can probably get away with only using a media query with your max-height 599 file...as long as you call it SECOND in your head tag. Since the media query is second, your browser should use all its rules OVER the first CSS presented - that is UNTIL the 599px height is reached - then it will shut itself off...leaving only the 'base' CSS available for use. (clear as mud, ay?)

Comment: Syntax help through Microsoft's site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530813.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can determine window size by Jquery

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

or

```
$(document).width();
$(document).height();
```

then change css

```
$("link").attr("href", "blue.css");
```

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 if($(document).height()  > 600 or $(window).height() > 600){

   $("link").attr("href", "600+.css");

 } else {

   $("link").attr("href", "600-.css");

 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works in all major browsers. No JS needed. Vertically/horizontally centered, scrollable, sticks to the top when content is larger than viewport.

HTML:

```
<div id="body">[your content goes here]</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

html {
    display: table;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Don't forget to apply the last rule, it will actually perform the horizontal centering.

Comment: Okay--this would totally rock--I'll try tomorrow!

Comment: Don't forget to put the id on your content container element - the #body selector in the last rule (of course you can change it for any other selector) will apply the "margin: 0 auto" property which does the actual horizontal centering.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JavaScript conditional to detect screen size.

`function x()` will handle inserting the CSS link in the `<head>` tag. All you need to do is call the function and pass in the CSS file name.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
<!--
function x(y) {
    var styles = y;
    var newSS = document.createElement('link');
    newSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
    newSS.href = 'data:text/css,' + styles;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);
}

if ((screen.width >= 1024) && (screen.height >= 768)) {
    x('file.css');
}
else {
    x('file1.css');
}
//-->
< /SCRIPT>
```

Comment: @hussein, thanks! But can you be more specific of how to show the external style sheet?

Comment: @ian_6500 use `document.write` to write your stylesheets. I updated the answer.

Comment: @ian_6500 i updated my answer. Try the new code i posted. I tested and it's working from my side.

Comment: @ian Yes this will work in all browsers. `appendChild` `getElementsByTagName`and `createElement` are supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a bit of googling and found this:

http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/detect-screen-size-css-style/

does that work for you?

Comment: This looks really promising! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Less CSS Framework: http://lessframework.com/,

You do not need JavaScript, but rather you can use CSS @Media to set styles based on resolution/ screen size.

Best of luck

Comment: Interesting, but I've built my whole site around 900px X 607px rectangle--a 2:3 apect ratio like a 35mm camera frame. I need everything to be compositionally relative... But I can see how that would be a really useful tool!

Comment: Ah, ok. Well then for future reference, it is definitely a very useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

If "document_height" not work, try "window_height" i comment it in code!

`$("link").attr("href", "css_file_path");` // here must insert path to your css, replace it in the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

document_height = $(document).height();
//window_height = $(window).height();

//if(window_height  > 600){
 if(document_height  > 600){
    alert('Bigger than 600px height: ' + $(document).height());
   $("link").attr("href", "600+.css"); // Here load css if window is bigger then 600px;

 } else {
    alert('Smaller than 600px height: ' + $(document).height());
   $("link").attr("href", "600-.css"); // Here load css if window is smaller then 600px;

 }
});

</script>
```

Comment: @user667776 Okay thanks!, will this work if I edit out the alerts?

Comment: Yes you can comment it, but you must set your css files path in $("link").attr("href", "600+.css");

Comment: @user667776 okay, this sort of works, but my sIFR and cufon gets messed up... http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/about/index2.html Please let me know what you think... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because you have two css styles in your site and script replace all of them!

Comment: Sure, but that's what I'm trying to do, switch between a style sheet set up for one size display, and another for a different size...

Comment: I found that you have two elements with "sIFR_replacement_0" same ID ("object ID" and "span ID"). Then you have same text two times.

Comment: Sure, one set of text is the sIFR flash projection and the other is the original HTML that the sIFR usually overlays...