# Javascript to create table based on screen width

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html-table, width

I have a 940 pixel wide table that currently contains all of the content to my website.

Using Javascript I'd like to test to see of the width of the browser is greater than 1240 and if so display my existing 940 pixel wide table in a `<td>` and display an advertisement in an adjacent `<td>` that's 300 pixels wide.

If the browser window is less that 1240 then I would just display my existing 940 pixel wide table.

Is there an way to test the width and set a flag then use Javascript to test that flag and include or not include my `<table> <tr> <td>` structure?

Comment: Just a hint: `document.documentElement.clientWidth` ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to load different CSS.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function x(y) {
        var styles = y;
        var newSS = document.createElement('link');
        newSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
        newSS.href = 'data:text/css,' + styles;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);
    }

    if (screen.width >= 1240) {
        x('largeTable.css');
    }
    else {
        x('smallTable.css');
    }
</scipt>
```

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365997/select-different-css-style-sheet-for-different-browser-window-sizes)

EDIT: This might help you accomplish what you are trying to do.
You could use javascript to load different CSS.

```
   if (screen.width >= 1240) {
       document.getElementById('advert').style.display = 'none';
    }
</scipt>
```

Comment: I was hoping to create some inside code rather than using css..any here that way?

Comment: Yeah. you could do that as well... Editing answer.